# How does Twitter do multipart file upload from the client app to its storage?

Tags: file-upload, twitter, server, architecture, backend

I am not speaking from the perspective of a user uploading a file to Twitter.  Rather, I want to *build* a twitter-like app and upload a file from my client app -> to my server -> to my s3 storage.

My current approach is to break the file up into chunks, and then upload it to my web server.  Then from my web server, I then upload it to s3 storage.

The part I am unsure about is *how* I should be storing it on the webserver before it goes to s3 storage.  Currently, I save it in memory, and once complete I send it to s3.  This consumes too much memory. The other approach is to store the file locally on the webserver, and then do the upload to s3.  Is this how a high traffic site usually do it?

This is an architecture based question. --> How is this done for a high traffic website like Twitter?

Comment: Conside using presigned url to upload https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: @TonyYip thanks.  This looks like a way to do it.  Checking it out now.